# Rewrite rule for clean url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a clean url for profiles on my website. For example I'd want this url

```
/profile?user=MrEasyBB
```

to become

```
/MrEasyBB
```

My current `htaccess` starts like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Which this should all work if I am correct. But what happens per say if the page url they type is

```
/help
```

There shouldn't be a user named `help`, and the page should direct to `help.php` instead. Can I write a rule to not follow a certain pattern? I'd also like to know to change the rule for images, comments, and so forth:

IE

```
/image/user/MrEasyBB/1239123871712194124.jpg
```

instead of

```
/image/picture.php?user=MrEasyBB&image=1239123871712194124.jpg
```

Which I am not positive on how to add multiples and to follow the pattern needed any suggestions on the rewrite rules if the first one won't work and how to do the second one?

I've also downloaded the `htaccess` cheatsheet pdf to learn a little more

Comment: Is `http://domain.com/image/user/MrEasyBB/1239123871712194124.jpg` correct & full path of the image?

Comment: yes persay it would be. There will be `.../image/user/...` and `.../video/user/...` the pattern I'd like to follow

Comment: If indeed `http://domain.com/image/user/MrEasyBB/1239123871712194124.jpg` is the correct path of image then your rule will not affect this image due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition which means do not execute rule for valid files.

Comment: No it's not the correct path of the image overall. it's the correct pattern I want to follow. The correct path would be located in a general image folder. I just don't allow direct access to it. Per say they go to `domain.com/image/1239....jpg` it won't give them access to this. I hope this is understandable. I just need the MrEasyBB part to know who's image is being liked in PHP. Though the image is in a section for all images.

Comment: Sorry it is still unclear. Please specify what image path you want to show to clients and what is the real path where these images will be found internally?

Comment: client path: `.../image/user/IMAGEPATH_AND_EXTENSION` and the real path is `.../image/IMAGEPATH_AND_EXTENSION` I am storing all images in a directory, but to get the information for likes,comments, etc I need the "owners" name to be present in the `get` and `post` whichever it may be

Answer (score 1):

You need to first have a rule for rewriting images to correct path and then your catch all rule will appear:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(image)/[^/]+/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This won't solve for the /help case, but if you don't mind /help.php, then it will be seen as an existing file, and serve that instead. Basically you will want to group URLs by their type/purpose, so in this case I would suggest `RewriteRule ^/user/(.+)$ profile.php?user=$1` so that `/user/MrEasyBB` goes to `profile.php?user=MrEasyBB`. This gives you room to make other rules to allow for different pages such as /help.

Comment: No doubt it is better and safer to have `/user/MrEasyBB` URLs. I just kept that rule same as your question as I didn't know if you would consider having `/user/MrEasyBB` URL instead of `/MrEasyBB`. It is edited now accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?image/user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)$ /image/picture.php?user=$1&image=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```